# React-redux - Call action with new state after other action updated state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an array of objects that can be updated by appending new elements to the array with the action function `addNewCategory(category)`

After the new category appended to the array, I want to rebuild a tree view that I created. The tree view uses the redux store object `tree`.

The tree gets build inside the action function `buildCategoriesTree`

Here are the functions:

```
export function addNewCategory(category) {
return {
    type: ADD_NEW_CATEGORY,
    payload: category
}
}

export function buildCategoriesTree(feecategories) {

let cats = feecategories.map(x => ({...x}));
let categories = {
    name: 'Kategorien',
    toggled: true,
    children:
        buildTreeFromCategories(cats)
};

return {
    type: GET_CATEGORIES_TREE,
    payload: categories
}
}
```

Now the problem is: when I call the `buildCategoriesTree(...)` function after the `addNewCategory(...)` function. The tree doesn't update. When I add another category, the tree updates with the category I added before. So it is alway one step behind.

How is it possible that the second function "waits" until the store is up  to date? I read about react-thunk, but I don't know if this is the correct solution for this kind of problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why shouldn't the reducer react to the `ADD_NEW_CATEGORY` and create the categories tree instead of dispatching another action? And even a better approach would have been to use a selector to create the categories tree whenever the categories change.

Comment: because to build the tree I need allCategories array from the store. The addNewCategory action only has the new category as a parameter.

Comment: However, the reducer has the state, and it can build the tree. In addition, you are storing a category twice (once as a category, and second in the derived tree), and you can use a selector to get the derived tree without storing it.

Comment: I read that I shouldn't add logic to the reducer. Can you show me what you mean with using a selector?

Comment: It's not logic, just state creation. However, I agree that you shouldn't do that in the reducer but for other reasons.

Comment: You can read more about derived data and selectors in the [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computingderiveddata).